# Caffe with natural language understaing

Tags: python, database, caffe, pycaffe

I'm using [Rotten Tomatoes database](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) as my dataset. Following [this code](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/data_helpers.py) I formatted the data. So, every sentence's size is 56 words, if a sentence's size is less than 56 words, this code puts some **PAD** to the end of sequence. For example, just for comprehension instead sentence is size 56, imagine it is 5:

Before:

```
complete_sentence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
not_complete_sentence = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

After:

```
complete_sentence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
not_complete_sentence = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'PAD', 'PAD']
```

After processing the data, I transform it to caffe datum:

```
datum = caffe.proto.caffe_pb2.Datum()
datum.channels = 1
datum.height = txt_array.shape[0] ## 56
datum.width = 1
datum.label = label
datum.data = txt_array.tobytes()
```

Where **label** is 0 or 1 (positive or negative review) and txt_array is a **formatted sentence** as **np.array**. And finally, I put this datum on two lmdbs, one for training and other for test.

I want known if is this good configuration to my dataset? For images I used something similar to it, but for text this configuration is valid too? Or do I have to do something different for text?

Comment: Did you try this [tutorial](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/)? It's using tensorflow, I think you can adapt to caffe.

Comment: Yes, I'm following it. But I don't known how to adapt using caffe. =(